# How Apache communicate with an Application Server

Tags: apache, http, webserver, passenger, reverse-proxy

I use Apache as ***Reverse Proxy***, and behind it I use [Phusion Passenger](https://www.phusionpassenger.com/)(a Rails Server) as ***Application Server***. I'm confused about how **Apache** communicate with **Phusion Passenger**(which is ***Application Server*** behind it).
Here is what I get of `httpd`:

```
> ps aux | grep /MyWebsite/bin/httpd
googly    8353  0.0  0.0  73856  3280 ?        Ss   Aug26   0:00 /MyWebsite/bin/httpd -d /MyWebsite -f var/state/apache-1080/httpd.conf
googly    8391  0.0  0.0  73856  1828 ?        S    Aug26   0:00 /MyWebsite/bin/httpd -d /MyWebsite -f var/state/apache-1080/httpd.conf
... # showing that 8353 forks 10 process, and 8353 is the father process
```

When a HTTP request comes, Apache allocates a process to handle this request(for example  process `8391`), passing it to the Application Server.

My question is, what is really happening about this? How Apache communicate with an Application Server? I think different Application Server are similar under this condition.

Does `8391` pass the request to Phusion Passenger? If so, Phusion Passenger should have its own separate process running, right? Or `8391` can be regarded as Phusion Passenger process and it can handle the request itself?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Apache accepts the request which is generated in term of thread
- It sends request back to your application server.
- Till it get response from Application server, Apache thread would be in waiting/running state.
- Apache sends back request to client.
- Apache closes connections once it acknowledges data.
- Application server thread closes once apache acknowledges data.

Comment: So you mean Apache has its process, and Application server also have its own process? But how Apache knows the process/port of the Application server? Apache listens port1, and Application server listens port2, port1 not equals port2, right?

Comment: You have used Apache as Reverse Proxy where you have mentioned details of which port does you application server connects to. Apache and application both would be tied up to expect response from Application to Apache. Port would only be helpful to identify which port to connect to. Apache or Application in general scenarios would have it's uniqueness based on headers/sessions and many other things to respond to appropriate process attached to it.

Comment: I find in httpd.conf, there is one line `Listen 1080`, does it mean Application server is using port 1080?

Comment: What is the purpose of asking above question, it doesn't have understanding with your original post.

Comment: Apache is listening port 1080, when it receives request, it use process 8391 to handle the request, my question is: What is process 8391 doing? Is process 8391 sends the request to Application server, and the Application server use another process to handle the request?

Comment: Yes your understanding is correct and explained in brief in my answer above. I am sure it would help.